# Auth and payment system for flask

Tags: python, wordpress, flask

I made a web app in Flask (python). It doesn't have auth and payment gate. Can I use webpress to make the landing page, authentication and payment system?.

Its my first project and I find it impossible to make the auth and payment system cuz I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Iam new to flask